# Do I need to restart Tomcat for its configuration changes to take effect?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am using Spring Boot, and I added the server.maxHttpHeaderSize key-value pair via application.yml, as the following.

```
server:
   max-http-header-size: 65536
```

More specifically, I set the maxHttpHeaderSize attribute value to 65536. Hence, changing it from the default value of 4096.

I wonder whether it is necessary to restart Tomcat for the change to take effect.

So, what do I need to do in order for my change to take effect?

Comment: Are you compiling Spring Boot to a war file or jar file?

Comment: Yes you need to restart application

Comment: @ian-lim I actually do not know. However, this is way I found in the logs for building: 
10:08:20 :processResources UP-TO-DATE
10:08:20 :classes UP-TO-DATE
10:08:20 :compileWebappGroovyPages NO-SOURCE
10:08:20 :compileGroovyPages
10:08:21 :compileGsonViews
10:08:31 :jar
10:08:33 :bootRepackage
10:08:36 :assemble
10:08:36 
10:08:36 BUILD SUCCESSFUL